# touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, touch, ntfs

I tried to run this command:

```
php -r "touch('/mnt/my_drive/test.txt', 1600981328);"
```

I got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted in Command line code on line 1
```

If I run it with `sudo`, I don't get the error.

`/mnt/my_drive` is an NTFS drive. The mount was created in `fsab` with `umask=000`, so I have no idea, why do I get permission error.

**Please do not mark this as a duplicate, because the similar questions have these answers:**

- Check the permissions: It should be right because of `umask=000`
- Run composer/php in elevated mode: I would like to avoid running the webserver as admin
- Modify some library files in vendor: I get this error even in command line, as my example shows
- Don't use ntfs: It is not my choice

Comment: Can you show us the mount line from fstab? If it works using sudo, it's definitely a permissions issue. If you have a `umask` defined in fstab, my first question is to check if there's a `uid` and/or `gid` defined as well?

Comment: Please add some details on the used scenario, like exact Linux distribution & version, PHP version and the current mount data with all options/flags? Thx

Answer (score 1):

This may happen when the user PHP runs as isn't the owner of the cache files. Checkout this link [Utime failed: Operation not permitted](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/20437-utime-failed-operation-not-permitted/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked perfectly on my machine with php7.4 and ntfs mounted with:

> /dev/sdaX on /mnt/tmp type fuseblk  rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)

Are you sure the directory you are trying to do this in allows you to create files? Does the directory exist?

If you can create normal files without setting the time parameter it might have something to do with ntfs or fuse mounting it.

In this case:
Try to run the php command in strace to see what actually fails, that should help nail down the error.

EDIT: Also the umask should not matter in this case, what matter are the permissions of the directories that contain the file.

Answer (score 0):

Updating file modification time fails unless issued by the owner. Try to clear the cache files and recreate them with the PHP user as the owner.

Answer (score -1):

It is never assumed a good point to change modification times, unless there is a need to file something in with others. It's hasty and shows no function to it. The only thing i can tell you is that you have to own the file, you may need root, just to access these permissions and that with sudo you can do anything. So you've no hope of this. I hope that can bring you to believe in some other way of a file system breakdown for your clients.

Comment: This is a minimal reproducible example. I do not want to call touch this way, but a library does.

Comment: @IterAtor Have you read the documentation? It can usually designate any problems in its own code. Also, if it's on GitHub, you can rest assuredly put an issue with the code up and be directly cared for by the author of the code.